# Why doesn't LuaJIT's FFI module require declared calling conventions?

Tags: ffi, luajit

This is something I've been curious about for a while: I was wondering how LuaJIT's FFI module manages to use the correct calling conventions for invoking external native functions without any need for declarations in the user's prototypes.

I tried reading through the source code to figure this out on my own, but finding what I was looking for proved to be too difficult, so any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit

In order to verify that calling conventions are auto-determined when not declared, I wrote the following 32-bit test DLL to be compiled with MSVC's C compiler:

```c
// Use multibyte characters for our default char type
#define _MBCS 1

// Speed up build process with minimal headers.
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN

// System includes
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CALLCONV_TEST(CCONV) \
    int __##CCONV test_##CCONV(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3) \
    { \
        return CALLCONV_WORK(arg1, arg2, arg3); \
        __pragma(comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__ )) \
    }

#define CALLCONV_WORK(arg1,arg2,arg3) \
    test_calls_work(__FUNCTION__, arg1, arg2, arg3, __COUNTER__);

static int test_calls_work(const char* funcname, int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3, int retcode)
{
    printf("[%s call]\n", funcname);
    printf("  arg1 => %d\n", arg1);
    printf("  arg2 => %f\n", arg2);
    printf("  arg3 => \"%s\"\n", arg3);
    printf("  <= return %d\n", retcode);
    return retcode;
}

CALLCONV_TEST(cdecl)     // => int __cdecl    test_cdecl(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3);
CALLCONV_TEST(stdcall)   // => int __stdcall  test_stdcall(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3);
CALLCONV_TEST(fastcall)  // => int __fastcall test_fastcall(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3);

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if(dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I then wrote an LUA script for calling the exported functions with the ffi module:

```lua
local ffi = require('ffi')
local testdll = ffi.load('ljffi-test.dll')

ffi.cdef[[
int test_cdecl(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3);
int test_stdcall(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3);
int test_fastcall(int arg1, float arg2, const char* arg3);
]]

local function run_tests(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    local function cconv_test(name)
        local funcname = 'test_' .. name
        local handler = testdll[funcname]
        local ret = tonumber(handler(arg1, arg2, arg3))
        print(string.format('  => got %d\n', ret))
    end

    cconv_test('cdecl')
    cconv_test('stdcall')
    cconv_test('fastcall')
end

run_tests(3, 1.33, 'string value')
```

After compiling the DLL and running the script, I received the following output:

```
[test_cdecl call]
  arg1 => 3
  arg2 => 1.330000
  arg3 => "string value"
  <= return 0
  => got 0

[test_stdcall call]
  arg1 => 3
  arg2 => 1.330000
  arg3 => "string value"
  <= return 1
  => got 1

[test_fastcall call]
  arg1 => 0
  arg2 => 0.000000
  arg3 => "(null)"
  <= return 2
  => got 2
```

As you can see, the ffi module accurately resolve the calling conventions for the `__cdecl` calling convention and the `__stdcall` calling convention. (but appears to have called the __fastcall function incorrectly)

Lastly, I've included dumpbin's output to show that all functions are being exported with undecorated names.

```
> dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS ljffi-test.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file ljffi-test.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for ljffi-test.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    548838D4 time date stamp Wed Dec 10 04:13:08 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           3 number of functions
           3 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 test_cdecl
          2    1 000010C0 test_fastcall
          3    2 00001060 test_stdcall

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .text
```

#### Edit 2

Just to clarify, since calling conventions are only really relevant for 32-bit Windows compilers, so that is the primary focus for this question. (Unless I'm mistaken, compilers targeting the Win64 platform only use the `FASTCALL` calling convention, and GCC uses the `CDECL` calling convention for all other platforms supported by LuaJIT)

As far as I know, the only place to find information about functions exported from a PE file is the `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY`, and if function names are exported without decorators, there is no information remaining that indicates the calling convention of a particular function.

Following that logic, the only remaining method I can think of for determining a function's calling convention is to analyze the assembly of the exported function, and determine the convention based on the stack usage. That seems like a bit much, though, when I consider the differences produced by different compilers and optimization levels.

Comment: My first impression that LuaJIT uses default __cdecl for all your test calls. Second call looks right, but it damages the stack. So next call produce bad output and you just lucky with no-crash. I cannot test it at the moment, try to reorder calls.

Comment: Yep, I went ahead and ran the calls through a debugger and just like you thought, all three functions were called using the __cdecl calling convention. Looks like I've just been lucky up to this point to have my code still function properly without the right conventions. Anyways, thanks to taking the time to clear up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling convention is something platform dependent.
Usually there is one platform's default and you may specify others.

From http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html:

> The C parser complies to the C99 language standard plus the following extensions:
>
> ...
>
> GCC **attribute** with the following attributes: aligned, packed, mode, vector_size, cdecl, fastcall, stdcall, thiscall.
>
> ...
>
> MSVC __cdecl, __fastcall, __stdcall, __thiscall, __ptr32, __ptr64,

Most interesting is Win32. Here calling convention maybe encoded with decorators [Win32 calling conventions](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv.html).

LuaJIT has code to recognize decorators.

Also, LuaJIT by default use __stdcall call convention for WinAPI Dlls: kernel32.dll, user32.dll and gdi32.dll.

Comment: (For the following, let's just assume I'm only talking about 32-bit DLLs on Windows) If I'm understanding your answer correctly, you're saying that the FFI module defaults to STDCALL conventions for the three mentioned system DLLs, and attempts to resolve the calling convention for everything else based on the names exported from the loaded DLL. That does appear to be true, but it doesn't account for how luajit still manages to use the proper calling convention when the function names are exported without decorators. (through use of a .def file or linker params) See my example above.